# Basic Programming Python3 practice question with runtime error from Hackerearth

Tags: python, compiler-errors

I am trying to solve a question where I am supposed to print the max number of a particular symbol that repeats continuously but I have to give inputs manually for each individual row. If I copy and paste the test cases it returns an error. Below is the full code and testcase with outputs given after.

NOTE: if not fully understood the problem please visit https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/maximum-border-9767e14c/

```
def maxborder(a):
    maxi=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        count=0
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            if(a[i][j]=='#'):
                count+=1
                if count> maxi:
                    maxi=count
    return maxi

no=int(input())
while(no!=0):
    m=int(input())
    n=int(input())
    a=[]
    for i in range(m):
        r=[]
        e=str(input())
        if len(e)!=0:
            for x in range(len(e)):
                r.append(e[x])
        a.append(r)
    res=maxborder(a)
    no-=1

print(res)
```

Test case and output,(full test case down below)

```
TESTCASE:
2 #loop_count(no)
2 15 #row and column(m and n)

.....####......
.....#.........

7 9 
...###...
...###...
..#......
.####....
..#......
...#####.
.........

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
4
5
```

What I get:

```
Execution failed.
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 : '2 15'

Stack Trace:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "something.py3",  line 26, in <module>
m=int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 15'
```

Full test case:

```
10
2 15
.....####......
.....#.........
7 9
...###...
...###...
..#......
.####....
..#......
...#####.
.........
18 11
.#########.
########...
.........#.
####.......
.....#####.
.....##....
....#####..
.....####..
..###......
......#....
....#####..
...####....
##.........
#####......
....#####..
....##.....
.#######...
.#.........
1 15
.....######....
5 11
..#####....
.#######...
......#....
....#####..
...#####...
8 13
.....######..
......##.....
########.....
...#.........
.............
#######......
..######.....
####.........
7 5
.....
..##.
###..
..##.
.....
..#..
.#...
14 2
..
#.
..
#.
..
#.
..
..
#.
..
..
..
#.
..
7 15
.###########...
##############.
...####........
...##########..
.......#.......
.....#########.
.#######.......
12 6
#####.
###...
#.....
##....
###...
......
.##...
..##..
...#..
..#...
#####.
####..
```

Expected output for the above test case:

```
4
5
9
6
7
8
3
1
14
5
```

Comment: In the code, n inputs two values; you try to convert it to one int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
def maxborder(a):
    maxi=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        count=0
        for j in range(len(a[0])):
            if(a[i][j]=='#'):
                count+=1
                if count> maxi:
                    maxi=count
    return maxi

no=int(input())
while(no!=0):
    t=input().split(" ")
    m=int(t[0])
    n=int(t[1])
    a=[]
    for i in range(m):
        r=[]
        e=str(input())
        if len(e)!=0:
            for x in range(len(e)):
                r.append(e[x])
        a.append(r)
    res=maxborder(a)
    no-=1

print(res)
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Could not figure it out. Add print(res) into while loop to get the full output. THX